# php - rotate PDF and convert into jpg without using any tools?

Tags: php, converters

I have almost no experience with php, but I've been wondering if it's possible to rotate a PDF and convert it into a jpg without using any extra tools like imagemagick or ghostscript in php. The reason why is that I can't install tools on my own, and paying a server administrator to install any tools is too expensive (in my case).

So, is it possible with php only?! 
It should be fast as well.

Thanks for help and tips.

Comment: Well, you could always research the format of a PDF file, and the format of a JPG file, and convert from one to another yourself from the ground up. But that's kinda what libraries like ImageMagick are for...

Comment: `and paying a server administrator to install any tools is too expensive`. It should not take more than 2 minutes to do that, and compare to how long it would take you to implement it, debug it, and maintain it whenever there is a security update, there is no better option than actually giving server admin 10$ to do it on server... Or alternatively, you can spin up an AWS instance that you send your requests to for processing.

Comment: What do you mean "extra tools"? Do you mean in Acrobat? ( Do you want "magic" (wave your hands) or Imagemagick)? -- wink

Comment: I'm searching a solution for my problem without telling a server administrator to install tool xy, because it costs around 90$/hour. @Dimi What exactly do you mean by AWS instances?